# Chiacchiere, frappe, bugie, cenci o crostoli?

Tags: word-usage

Questi tipici dolcetti di carnevale hanno  diverse varianti regionali nel nome : [image]

Sono chiamati: Bugie (in Piemonte e Liguria); chiacchere (in Lombardia); cenci (in Toscana); fiocchetti (in Romagna); grostoi (in Trentino); crostoli o galani (in Veneto); intrigoni (in Emilia); meraviglie (in Sardegna); frappe, frappole o sfrappole (in Italia centrale).

La mia domanda è:

Qual è, se c’è, il loro nome in italiano?

Comment: Tutti quanti, credo...

Comment: Se si cerca ["frappa" nel dizionario di Sinonimi e Contrari Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/frappa_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)) si trova: «**2.** (*gastron., region.*) [nell'Italia centr., dolce del periodo di carnevale, ritagliato da una sfoglia in forma di nastri o rettangoli e fritto e cosparso di zucchero] ≈ (*region.*) cencio, (*region.*) chiacchiera.» Quindi non sembra che esista un nome per questi dolci che non venga considerato un regionalismo.